# How to get chan value from an interface and use it in reflect.Select(...)

Tags: go

I took an example of reflect.Select from:
 **https://www.socketloop.com/references/golang-reflect-select-and-selectcase-function-example**

It works as far as it goes.  But it was creating the reflect.Value() from a simple
"chan" := make(chan int) setup.

But I wanted to use a channel from a structure passed as an interface{}.

So I modified the program to create a struct and pass it to the processing as
an interface parameter.

When run I get:  **panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Valuepanic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value**

This is strange because I the exact code another program that works!!

```
func inspect(f interface{}) map[string]string {

    m := make(map[string]string)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(f).Elem()

    for i := 0; i < val.NumField(); i++ {
        valueField := val.Field(i)
        typeField := val.Type().Field(i)
        f := valueField.Interface()

        val := reflect.ValueOf(f)
        m[typeField.Name] = val.String()
    }

    return m
}
```

Can any
body tell me where I am going wrong trying to use the interface code
in replace of the simple variable version.

The program is below with comments showing changes:

```
package main

// Original Example from:
// https://www.socketloop.com/references/golang-reflect-select-and-selectcase-function-example
//
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    // following replaces  " var sendCh := make(chan int) "
    type Foo struct {
        Ch chan int
    }
    sendCh := Foo{make(chan int)}
    // End of replacement code

    var increaseInt = func(c chan int) {
        for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }

    go increaseInt(sendCh.Ch)

    // This routine call replaces the code incorporated in "runJob"
    // It was done so I could call through an empty interface{}
    runJob(sendCh)
    // End replaement code--
}

func runJob(f interface{}) {
    var selectCase = make([]reflect.SelectCase, 1)

    // This code replaces just using the orginal "sendCh" value
    // I am trying here to construct "sendCh" from the interface value
    val := reflect.ValueOf(f).Elem()
    valueField := val.Field(0)
    sendCh := valueField.Interface()
    // End of replacement code

    selectCase[0].Dir = reflect.SelectRecv
    selectCase[0].Chan = reflect.ValueOf(sendCh)

    counter := 0
    for counter < 1 {
        chosen, recv, recvOk := reflect.Select(selectCase) // <--- here
        if recvOk {
            fmt.Println(chosen, recv.Int(), recvOk)

        } else {
            fmt.Println("Exit Condition Detected:  ", chosen, recv.Int(), recvOk)
            counter++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error message has told.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to not do reflection but do type assertion instead. So you could say:

```
val, ok := f.(Foo)
if !ok {
    fmt.Printf("Not Foo? Try Bar.\n")
}
sendCh := val.Ch
```

---

Alternatively, if you insist on using `reflect` (which is an inferior solution here) you could get what you want by dropping `Elem()`. For example:

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(f)
valueField := val.FieldByName("Ch")
sendCh := valueField.Interface()
```

Or even `val.Field(0)` if you don't want to use the name. Again, the type assertion method is better than this.

Comment: I get "undefined: Foo".   I understand the concept, but there must be a

Comment: reason it does not work.  Using the reflection example worked fine and all i did was replace the reflection code with the type assertion code as you suggested.  Any clues -- Did you test your fix?  Why does it not see Foo?

Comment: @Godfather In your example Foo is inside a function, not visible outside. Try moving it out of the function. Then try reading Effective Go :)

Comment: Thanks - Youthful naive goes on a short time - stupid goes on forever!

Comment: Question, since i need to do the type assertion inside the function since I am working from an interface value sent from outside the function, the only way for it to work is define Foo again inside function, not good coding practice.  So within the function the reflection method is really the only thing that will work - right!

Comment: @Godfather But you can define your Foo struct outside of any function. Then any function will be able to see it (any package really, since it's Capitalized).

Comment: You are right again -- I should read my own code - I thought I defined it